# Pokemon sword game card and digital expansion pack

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

Trying to help my son.  He has a gamecard for pokemon sword. He purchased the expansion pack from the online store and can't get them to work together.  Can anyone help me.  The meltdown is real.

Comment: Did you check which version of the expansion that was purchased?  Each version of the game has its own respective expansions, and they aren’t compatible with the other version

Comment: What exactly did he purchase? What exact error is he having? Does he get a specific error message when he tries to download the pack? Does the game crash when he tries to access it?

Answer (score 2):

As per Wondercricket's comment, the expansion pack must match the game version. If your son purchasd the expansion pack for Pokemon Shield, it will not work with the gamecard for Pokemon Sword.